# Conflicting Parameter Definition

Tags: assembly, masm, masm32, irvine32

In this program, I'm trying to appends a source string to the end of a destination string. But when I tried to run the program, it gives me error in this line.

```
strLength PROTO,
    stringLength:PTR BYTE
```

This is what it says: 
Error   A2111   conflicting parameter definition

I have been trying to fix the code, but still have no idea with what is wrong. And this is the whole code:

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

strCat PROTO,
    sourceFrom:PTR BYTE,
    targetTo:PTR BYTE

strLength PROTO,
    stringLength:PTR BYTE

.data
Source1 BYTE "Testtttttt", 0h
NoSpace1 BYTE "This string should cause an error. for the user if you try to concatenate Source1 to it. ", 0h

.code
main PROC
INVOKE strCat, ADDR Source1, ADDR NoSpace1
exit
main ENDP

strCat PROC USES ESI EDI ECX EAX,
    sourceFrom:PTR BYTE,
    targetTo:PTR BYTE
;--------------------------------------------------------------------------
;appends a source string to the end of a destination string
;receives: pointer to source, pointer to target
;return: nothing
;--------------------------------------------------------------------------
INVOKE strLength, targetTo          ;EBX = length
mov ECX, EBX                            ;mov the stringLength to ECX

end:                                    ;look for end of line
mov EAX, BYTE PTR[sourceFrom]           ;sourcefrom to EAX
cmp EAX, ' '                            ;compare with space
inc EAX
jne end
next:
inc EAX
cmp EAX, ' '                            ;compare with space
jne end                                 ;if not space go to the next character

INVOKE strLength, sourceFrom        ;EBX = length
mov ECX, EBX                            ;mov the stringLength to ECX
mov ESI, sourceFrom                     ;ESI points to source
mov EDI, targetTo                       ;EDI points to target
cld                                     ;direction forward
rep movsb

ret
strCat ENDP

strLength PROC USES EDI,
    stringTo:PTR BYTE
;--------------------------------------------------------------------------
;find the length of the string
;receives: pointer to string
;return: length of string in EAX
;--------------------------------------------------------------------------
mov EDI, stringTo
mov EBX, 0                              ;set EAX to 0

loop1:
cmp BYTE PTR [EDI], 0                   ;check if it is the end of string
je loop2                                ;if it is the end go to loop2
inc edi                                 ;if not, next characters
inc EBX
jmp loop1

loop2:
ret
strLength ENDP

END main
```

Comment: @PeterCordes : In the context of a PROTO it would be correct.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: thanks for the correction.  Random guessing is of course usually the wrong way to solve syntax errors, but I thought changing `PTR BYTE` to `BYTE PTR` had a decent possibility of being the solution.

Comment: Wherever you have `PROTO` replace it with `PROTO C` to specify a calling convention, Replace `PROC` with `PROC C`. You use the label `end:`. That will conflict with the `END` directive. Rename label `END` to something else like `ENDIT`. `mov EAX, BYTE PTR[sourceFrom]` will likely cause issues since you are trying move a BYTE into a 32 bit register. You may be able to use `movzx EAX, BYTE PTR[sourceFrom]` to zero extend the BYTE into the 32-bit register _EAX_

Comment: Remove the `,`s after your `PROTO` keywords/`PROC USES ...` keywords. It should look like this: `strLength PROTO stringLength: PTR BYTE`.

Comment: @zx485 : I believe that if you make your `PROTO` multiline you'll need the `,` after `PROTO` and at the end of the registers listed in `USES`. If you put the definitions all on one line then you need to remove the `,`  as you suggest.